# Assign values of array to separate variables in one line

Tags: c#, arrays, string, initialization, declaration

Can I assign each value in an array to separate variables in one line in C#?  Here's an example in Ruby code of what I want:

```
irb(main):001:0> str1, str2 = ["hey", "now"]
=> ["hey", "now"]
irb(main):002:0> str1
=> "hey"
irb(main):003:0> str2
=> "now"
```

I'm not sure if what I'm wanting is possible in C#.

**Edit:**  for those suggesting I just assign the strings "hey" and "now" to variables, that's not what I want.  Imagine the following:

```
irb(main):004:0> val1, val2 = get_two_values()
=> ["hey", "now"]
irb(main):005:0> val1
=> "hey"
irb(main):006:0> val2
=> "now"
```

Now the fact that the method `get_two_values` returned strings "hey" and "now" is arbitrary.  In fact it could return any two values, they don't even have to be strings.

Comment: Wow, ugly and confusing.  Reminds me of my last date.

Comment: @Will: Really? I think it's nice and succinct, while still being clear and readable. I rather like the feature in python and use it frequently.

Comment: From a C# perspective, definitely.  It looks like you're assigning a reference to a single array to two different varaibles... like str1 = new string[] {"one","two"}; str2 = str1;  So its immediately confusing to C# developers.  The ugly bit was just so I could fit in the joke.

Comment: Perhaps if C# is your only language, then yes, I suppose it looks kinda ugly. Maybe you should consider broadening your horizons? Anyway, although I've never developed in ruby, I've done a ton in python, so that assignment is not new to me at all. It looks like a simple tuple creation and an unpack (also called a tuple assignment). Although Ruby apparently uses brackets [] rather than parens () like python, it's otherwise syntactically identical. Based on comments from @Sarah, I expect it functions identically.

Comment: I think Will is referring to the command line portion of the example. Not having done Ruby I did a double take myself. The assignment itself is succinct, clear, and readable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47816647/1225421

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is not possible in C#.

The closest thing I can think of is to use initialization in the same line with indexs

```
strArr = new string[]{"foo","bar"};
string str1 = strArr[0], str2 = strArr[1];
```

Comment: That's essentially what ruby does under the covers; the thing @Sarah wants to do is basically syntactic sugar.

Comment: I'd call it syntactic s-omething.  Does Ruby hide the differences between memory allocation of primitives and reference types???

Comment: Ruby is a scripting language. There are no primitive types; they're all on the heap -- reference types.

Answer (score 15):

**Update:** In C#7 you can easily assign multiple variables at once using tuples. In order to assign array elements to variables, you'd need to write an appropriate `Deconstruct()` extension methods:

> Another way to consume tuples is to deconstruct them. A deconstructing
>   declaration is a syntax for splitting a tuple (or other value) into
>   its parts and assigning those parts individually to fresh variables:
>
> ```
> (string first, string middle, string last) = LookupName(id1); // deconstructing declaration
> WriteLine($"found {first} {last}.");
> ```
>
> In a deconstructing declaration you can use var for the individual
>   variables declared:
>
> ```
> (var first, var middle, var last) = LookupName(id1); // var inside
> ```
>
> Or even put a single var outside of the parentheses as an
>   abbreviation:
>
> ```
> var (first, middle, last) = LookupName(id1); // var outside
> ```
>
> You can also deconstruct into existing variables with a deconstructing
>   assignment:
>
> ```
> (first, middle, last) = LookupName(id2); // deconstructing assignment
> ```
>
> Deconstruction is not just for tuples. Any type can be deconstructed,
>   as long as it has an (instance or extension) deconstructor method of
>   the form:
>
> ```
> public void Deconstruct(out T1 x1, ..., out Tn xn) { ... }
> ```
>
> The out parameters constitute the values that result from the
>   deconstruction.
>
> (Why does it use out parameters instead of returning a tuple? That is
>   so that you can have multiple overloads for different numbers of
>   values).
>
> ```
> class Point
> {
>     public int X { get; }
>     public int Y { get; }
>
>     public Point(int x, int y) { X = x; Y = y; }
>     public void Deconstruct(out int x, out int y) { x = X; y = Y; }
> }
>
> (var myX, var myY) = GetPoint(); // calls Deconstruct(out myX, out myY);
> ```
>
> It will be a common pattern to have constructors and deconstructors be
>   “symmetric” in this way.
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

---

**Old answer:**

In fact, you can achieve similar functionality in C# by using extension methods like this (note: I haven't include checking if arguments are valid):

```
public static void Match<T>(this IList<T> collection, Action<T,T> block)
{
    block(collection[0], collection[1]);
}
public static void Match<T>(this IList<T> collection, Action<T,T,T> block)
{
    block(collection[0], collection[1], collection[2]);
}
//...
```

And you can use them like this:

```
new[] { "hey", "now" }.Match((str1, str2) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(str1);
    Console.WriteLine(str2);
});
```

In case a return value from a function is needed, the following overload would work:

```
public static R Match<T,R>(this IList<T> collection, Func<T, T, R> block)
{
    return block(collection[0], collection[1]);
}

private string NewMethod1()
{   
    return new[] { "hey", "now" }.Match((str1, str2) =>
    {
        return str1 + str2;
    });
}
```

In this way:

- You avoid having to repeat array name like in solution proposed by JaredPar and others; the list of "variables" is easy to read.
- You avoid having to explicitly declare variables types like in Daniel Earwicker's solution.

The disadvantage is that you end up with additional code block, but I think it's worth it. You can use code snippets in order to avoid typing braces etc. manually.

I know it's a 7 years old question, but not so long time ago I needed such a solution - easy giving names to array elements passed into the method (no, using classes/structs instead of arrays wasn't practical, because for same arrays I could need different element names in different methods) and unfortunately I ended up with code like this:

```
var A = points[0];
var A2 = points[1];
var B = points[2];
var C2 = points[3];
var C = points[4];
```

Now I could write (in fact, I've refactored one of those methods right now!):

```
points.Match((A, A2, B, C2, C) => {...});
```

---

*My solution is similar to pattern matching in F# and I was inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2321922/6659843*

Answer (score 4):

The real-world use case for this is providing a convenient way to return multiple values from a function. So it is a Ruby function that returns a fixed number of values in the array, and the caller wants them in two separate variables. This is where the feature makes most sense:

```
first_name, last_name = get_info() // always returns an array of length 2
```

To express this in C# you would mark the two parameters with `out` in the method definition, and return `void`:

```
public static void GetInfo(out string firstName, out string lastName)
{
    // assign to firstName and lastName, instead of trying to return them.
}
```

And so to call it:

```
string firstName, lastName;
SomeClass.GetInfo(out firstName, out lastName);
```

It's not so nice. Hopefully some future version of C# will allow this:

```
var firstName, lastName = SomeClass.GetInfo();
```

To enable this, the `GetInfo` method would return a `Tuple<string, string>`. This would be a non-breaking change to the language as the current legal uses of `var` are very restrictive so there is no valid use yet for the above "multiple declaration" syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line, but not as one statement.

For example:

```
int str1 = "hey"; int str2 = "now";
```

Python and ruby support the assignment you're trying to do; C# does not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use named tuples with [C# 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/) now.

```
{
  (string part1, string part2) = Deconstruct(new string[]{"hey","now"});
}

public (string, string) Deconstruct(string[] parts)
{
   return (parts[0], parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: a lot more code than simple straight assignment. And not even generic

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure if what I'm wanting is
>   possible in C#.

It's not.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can initialize an array of strings:

```
string[] strings = new string[] {"hey", "now"};
```

Although that's probably not too useful for you. Frankly its not hard to put them on two lines:

```
string str1 = "hey";
string str2 = "now";
```