# Some F# Features that I would like to see in C#

Tags: c#, f#

After messing about with F# there are some really nice features that I think I am going to miss when I HAVE to go back to C#, any clues on how I can ween myself off the following, or better still duplicate their functionality:

- Pattern Matching (esp. with Discriminating Unions)
- Discriminating Unions
- Recursive Functions (Heads and Tails on Lists)

And last but not least the Erlang inspired Message Processing.

Comment: Nope, all you can do is convince others to adopt F#.

Comment: @gradbot If only, but the pointy headed people I work for are not buying into my schemings, so need some nice little bits of code that fake me into thinking that I am still working in F#.

Comment: Are you suggesting that C# does not support recursion, or are you talking about the specific instance of a function *delegate* that takes another instance of the same function delegate as an argument? Because if it's the former, you're very wrong, and if it's the latter, I cannot think of any possible reason why you would need this in C# (lists are data structures and data structures can be, and often are, recursively defined, you don't need recursive delegates for that).

Comment: What you really want to ask is: "How can I persuade pointed-headed people to let me use F#?" That would be a useful, interesting, and slightly-more-answerable question.

Comment: How to convince your manager to use a functional language was something that came up in "park bench" discussion at the "Functional Programming eXchange" [1] conference I organised. My favorite answer (from someone who had done this) was anticipate the projects coming up, pick the most interesting/critical, write this in functional language in your spare time, when manager see a working solution, he will accept that it's written in a functional language.
[1] http://skillsmatter.com/event/cloud-grid/functional-programming-exchange-2009

Comment: @Aaronaught I know that you can coherce C# into doing recursive delegates through combinators, the head and tail stuff in F# I find to be smart, especially when doing boring loops. Yes you can get C# to do all the code bits, as everything boils down to the magic that is the CLR. Why do I want it all in C#, simple, makes testing a cinche, easier to read, and I prefer the style of functional programming over that of a mixed of procedural/Object of C#. Not knocking C#, after all it pays the bills, but if I can do what I love in my day to day code using a mainstream language, then how cool is that

Comment: @Robert Erlang inspired Message Processing is the most convincing argument that I can come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to what extent is this really a question. However, here are some typical patterns that I use to encode these functional constructs in C# (some of them come from my book, which has a [source code available](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/realworldfp)).

**Discriminated unions** - there is really no good way to implement discriminated unions in C# - the only thing you can do is to implement them as a class hierarchy (with a base class representing the DU type and a derived class for each of the DU case). You can also add `Tag` property(of some `enum` type) to the base class to make it easer to check which case the class represents. As far as I know, this is used in LINQ expression trees (which really should be discriminated union).

**Pattern matching** - you'll probably never get this in a fully general way (e.g. with nested patterns), but you can simulate pattern matching on discriminated unions like this (using the `Option<int>` type which is either `Some of int` or `None`):

```
Option<int> value = GetOption();
int val;
if (value.TryMatchSome(out val)) 
  Console.WriteLine("Some {0}", val);
else if (value.TryMatchNone()) 
  Console.WriteLine("None");
```

Not perfect, but at least you get a relatively nice way to extract values from the cases.

**Message passing** - there is [Concurrency and Coordination Runtime](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=2&ved=0CAwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb648752.aspx&rct=j&q=concurrency+and+coordination+runtime&ei=3jKgS6S7MMyHkAXBs7HUDA&usg=AFQjCNFxZGL9m_QDWlvlkRNOpiLSG_q8bA&sig2=J0wX-jxL13jrxuB3v3lMdA), which is in some ways also based on message passing and can be used in C#. I bet you could also use F# mailbox processor from C# using a technique based on iterators, which I described in [this article](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async.aspx) and is also used in Wintellect PowerThreading library. However, I don't think anybody implemented a solid message passing library based on this idea.

In summary, you can simulate many functional features in C#, at least to some extend and use some other without any problems (lambda functions and higher-order functions). However, if you need the full power of F#, then you just need to convince your company to start using F# :-).

Comment: This is what I like to see, We need answers, and that is one! :)

Comment: Message passing outside of the F# syntax looks expensive as in not free beer. I Have ended up writing my own message based system, then looked at the code and realised that all I had done was a little of what WCF already offers. HTTP call back were pretty cool mind. All a little too much in the style of Twisted Matrix. Ended up using Twisted instead. :)

Answer (score 7):

Use [F# to make reusable libraries you can call from C#](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-webcast-objects.aspx).

One very nice thing about F# is that it is still a .NET language.  You can mix and match languages in the CLR as much as you'd like...

Comment: hmmmm exposing some of the classes from the f# world to c# brings up some hairy looking classes. Tuples for example for the easiest of them look and feel alien, described in another problem post.

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: You typically want to hide those "features" under a level of abstraction.  You can usually make a reasonable API using .NET classes, and then do the work in F# using tuples and other things that would seem odd from the C# side of things...

Comment: Trouble is, when the guys start poking around in the SVN they will come across the F# and start complaining. Yes I agree that all .net languages have a place in this world, but for software houses that have a vested interest in code that isn't owned by oneself, they like to keep their code in one language only.

Answer (score 2):

Discriminated unions and pattern matching can be simulated in C#, although the type definitions are a bit verbose (see [How can I duplicate the F# discriminated union type in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320919/how-can-i-duplicate-the-f-discriminated-union-type-in-c) for some ideas).  Here's the approach I advocated in that question: an F# type `type T = ACase of A | BCase of B | CCase of C` can be represented by a C# abstract class with some static helper methods.

```
public abstract class T {
    public abstract X Match<X>(Func<A,X> aCase, Func<B,X> bCase, Func<C,X> cCase);

    private class ACase : T {
        private A a;
        public ACase(A a) { this.a = a; }

        public override X Match<X>(Func<A,X> aCase, Func<B,X> bCase, Func<C,X> cCase) {
            return aCase(a);
        }
    }
    private class BCase : T {
        private B b;
        public BCase(B b) { this.b = b; }

        public override X Match<X>(Func<A,X> aCase, Func<B,X> bCase, Func<C,X> cCase) {
            return bCase(b);
        }
    }
    private class CCase : T {
        private C c;
        public CCase(C c) { this.c = c; }

        public override X Match<X>(Func<A,X> aCase, Func<B,X> bCase, Func<C,X> cCase) {
            return cCase(c);
        }
    }

    public static T MakeACase(A a) { return new ACase(a); }
    public static T MakeBCase(B b) { return new BCase(b); }
    public static T MakeCCase(C c) { return new CCase(c); }
}
```

Matching now looks similar to F#, but without case labels.  The equivalent of this F# code:

```
function
| A a -> 1
| B b -> 2
| C c -> 3
```

Is this C# code:

```
public static int MatchDemo(T t) {
    return t.Match(
        a => 1,
        b => 2,
        c => 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out

[switch / pattern matching idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156467/switch-pattern-matching-idea)

for some crazy ways to attempt to do pattern-matching in C#.