# Is this matching from Scala is available in C#?

Tags: c#

I found nice little one example of Scala today. Something like:

```
(1 to 100) map { x =>   
  (x % 2, x % 6) match {  
    case (0,0) => "First"
    case (0,_) => "Second"    
    case (_,0) => "Third"    
    case _ => x toString    
  }
} foreach println
```

And i wonder if I could do something similar in C#. I tried to search on my own but it's hard since I don't know name of this expression. It seems pretty useful. So can I do this in C#?

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320919/how-can-i-duplicate-the-f-discriminated-union-type-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called (functional) pattern matching, and is a hallmark of functional programming languages such as Scala, F#, and Haskell.  http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2008/09/16/functional-c-pattern-matching/ discusses how to simulate F#'s version of it in C#.

Answer (score 5):

Pattern matching is not available in C#.

But you can use [Nemerle](https://code.google.com/p/nemerle/) .Net language which supports [Pattern Matching](http://nemerle.org/Grok_Variants_and_matching) and many [other great stuff](http://nemerle.org/wiki/index.php?title=Nemerle_object_modifier) which C# doesn't support.

```
foreach (x in $[1 .. 100])
{
   Console.WriteLine(
     match((x % 2, x % 6))
     {
       | (0, 0) => "First"
       | (0, _) => "Second"
       | (_, 0) => "Third"
       | _      => x.ToString()
     })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know Scala, I can't verify that this does the same thing, but you can probably base your code off this.

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
    .Select(x => new {original = x, two = x % 2, six = x % 6})
    .Select(x =>
    {
        if (x.two == 0 && x.six == 0)
            return "First";
        else if (x.two == 0)
            return "Second";
        else if (x.six == 0)
            return "Third";
        else
            return x.original.ToString();
    }).ToList().ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Outputs:

```
1
Second
3
Second
5
First
7
Second
9
Second
...
```

Comment: Is that what the Scala code actually does? I don't get the Scala code, but I'm pretty sure you're code can never print "Third". (Quick check - it doesn't - http://ideone.com/redmN )

Comment: Nice feature. I'll change my code to reflect the Scala output.