# c# 7.x how to split an array into variables

Tags: c#-7.0

I have a string `"06:55,13:55"`

I am trying to split it into variables:

```
var (mytime1, mytime2) = runTimes.Split(',');
```

but the compiler throws an error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS8129  No suitable Deconstruct instance or extension method was
>   found for type 'string[]', with 2 out parameters and a void return
>   type. AA.Integrations.Aexp.Main   C:\Users\username\Projects\AA\aci-integrations\AA.Integrations.Aexp.Main\SchedulerRegistry.cs   13  Active

Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does C# 7 have array/enumerable destructuring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815660/does-c-sharp-7-have-array-enumerable-destructuring)

Answer (score 6):

As the compiler clearly stated, there's no `Deconstruct` instance or extension method was found for type `string[]`, with 2 out parameters and a `Void` return type.

If you really think you need one, you can make your own:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Deconstruct(this string[] array, out string s1, out string s2)
    {
        s1 = array[0];
        s2 = array[1];
    }
}
```