Is it possible to pass an object to fill both paramaters in a method at once?
I have a function to set the X limits of a graph which works through two parts.
public double[] XAxisLimitFunc(int NextDataIndex)
{
    int X = NextDataIndex / 50;
    X = X * 50;
    double [] XNew = { X, X + 50 };
    return XNew;
}

and I want to be able to pass this result into another method
Graph.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX(XAxisLimitFunc(NextDataIndex)[0],XAxisLimitFunc(NextDataIndex)[1]);

I was wondering if it's at all possible to do it in one go, i.e. return the required parameters in one go so that it would look like this piece of code below.
Graph.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX(XAxisLimitFunc(NextDataIndex));

I'm not sure if it is and if this is a stupid question so be it, thanks in advance!
I initially tried to pass an array through with both doubles required to meet the parameters.

Technically - yes, you can do it. But because you have an array, your each parameter will be executing this method separately and this is extra processing. This is just overthinking. Assign result and use it in the next call.
double[] result = XAxisLimitFunc(NextDataIndex);    
Graph.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX(result[0], result[1]);

In your case however, the method you've created is not very resource demanding but at the same time it is not very sense making either. You basically have a need for  structure like Point only double. So you declare your struct
public struct DoublePoint
{
    public double X {get; set;}
    public double Y {get; set;}
}

And instead of double [] XNew = { X, X + 50 }; do var dp = new DoublePoint { X = X, Y = X + 50 };. Then your func call will be
var dp = XAxisLimitFunc(NextDataIndex);
Graph.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX(dp.X, dp.Y);


Additional thing to remember, this is not a good practice to use tuples in public methods because tuples cant's be documented well. You probably never see method return type tuple in any serious library

You can't do it exactly like you want.
The best option here is either refactoring Graph.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX() to accept an array, which I expect is not your method to change, or using two lines of code:
var xLimits = XAxisLimitFunc(NextDataIndex);
Graph.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX(xLimits[0], xLimits[1]);


Another thing worth exploring is ValueTuple, which again won't change much if you can't modify Graph.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX() but I feel like it's cleaner for your own part of the code, giving you named fields and good encapsulation and performance without needing to a define a whole type:
public static (double Low, double High) XAxisLimitFunc(int NextDataIndex)
{
    int X = NextDataIndex / 50;
    X = X * 50;
    return( X * 1.0, X + 50.0 );
}

var xLimits = XAxisLimitFunc(NextDataIndex);
Graph.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX(xLimits.Low, xLimits.High);


I suppose you could also wrap Graph.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX() with your own method:
// could use an array here, too
void SetXLimits((double Low, double High) Limits)
{
    Graph.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX(Limits.Low, Limits.High)
}

SetXLimits(XAxisLimitFunc(50));

But that seems like more complexity than it's worth, and if you wanted to do that you could build it into XAxisLimitFunc() in the first place.

With C# 11, you can destruct with List Patterns (see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74393591/112968 for more examples). I think this is the closest you are going to get.
if (XAxisLimitFunc(NextDataIndex) is [var first, var second]) {
  Graph.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX(first, second);
}


public Tuple<double, double> XAxisLimitFunc(int NextDataIndex)
{
    int X = NextDataIndex / 50;
    X = X * 50;
    return Tuple.Create(X, X + 50);
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
